# GCC shared library linked but header file in library not found

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

So I have some trouble using shared libraries in combination with GCC.
I'm quite new to this so that's why I came to ask it here. I was unable to find a question on stack overflow that helps me with mine (maybe i overlooked one). But first something about my setup and what I'm trying to accomplish.

So I have these two libraries that are development parallel to each other. One is named liblinkedlist, which contains the linkedlist implementation in C and the other is named libgraph, containing a graph implementation in C. Both are put in the following folder structure:

```
<root>
+---graph_lib(folder)
    +---build(folder)
    +---src(folder)
    +---makefile(file)
+---linkedlist_lib
    +---build(folder)
    +---src(folder)
    +---makefile(file)
```

Each src folder contains the source files (linkedlist.h and .c for liblinkedlist and graph.h and .c for libgraph)
In each build folder the .o and .so files created from the header files are stored.

Now the problem is that I want to use the liblinkedlist.so in /linkedlist_lib/build/ in my graph library. While compiling the libraries everything seems to go well. But when I try to use it in combination with including a header file (which is inside the linkedlist library), I get the message that it could not be found.

My compile commands are the following:
For the liblinkedlist:

```
gcc -fpic -c src/linkedlist.c -o build/linkedlist.o
gcc -shared -o build/liblinkedlist.so build/linkedlist.o
```

And for the libgraph wich uses the liblinkedlist:

```
gcc -fpic -c src/libgraph.c -o build/libgraph.o
gcc -fpic -c src/graph.c -o build/graph.o
gcc -L../linkedlist_lib/build/ -o build/libgraph build/libgraph.o build/graph.o -llinkedlist
```

These are the command and errors I get when using the header file:

```
gcc -fpic -c src/libgraph.c -o build/libgraph.o
In file included from src/libgraph.c:2:0:
src/graph.h:4:24: fatal error: linkedlist.h: File or folder does not exist
#include "linkedlist.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/libgraph.o] Fout 1
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem, am I doing something wrong here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which of these commands gives you an error ? Copy paste the error to your post so we can see it too.

Comment: Sure, I added it in the last codeblock. It's for compiling the graph.h file wich includes the linkedlist.h file

Comment: Use -I option to specify directories with headers (see [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) for details)

Comment: But I don't want the header file to be imported directly, but through the library file (liblibrary.so). Than it doesn't matter where the header file is located cause it's position independent, right?.

Comment: In C and C++ library files do not contain this information and header files have to be specified separately. See [this](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/images/GCC_CompilationProcess.png) picture describing build process (the first one in google search results). Library files are only used at step 4 by linker to compose resulting binary but header files are need at step 1 even by preprocessor.

Comment: After some reading in the docs you specified I managed to fix the  problem. Thanks for that.